# Mongoose cursor get size of stream

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database-cursor

Good Morning,

I'm making a database request to my MongoDB through Mongoose ODM in javascript. This request returns a stream (use of mongoose cursor function).

```
function findQuotes(from, to) {
  const selection = [
    'policyholder',
    'terms.startDate',
    'terms.variant',
  ];

  return Draft.find({
    lastPriceRequest: { $ne: null },
    updatedAt: {
      $gte: from.toISOString(),
      $lte: to.toISOString(),
    },
  })
    .select(selection.join(' '))
    .lean(true)
    .cursor({ batchSize: 200 }); 
}
```

I'm iterating through this stream by using Mongoose eachAsync function. During this iteration, every 50 drafts, I would like to send them to a specific endpoint API. 
This API endpoint only accepts POST request (JSON stream is not possible in our case).

For making that code working I need the number of documents in the cursor. Otherwise, It will never send the lasts drafts that are smaller than 50.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {timestamp} from
 * @param {timestamp} to
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
async function exportQuotes(from, to) {
  let i = 1;
  let res = [];

  const quotes = findQuotes(from, to);

  return quotes.eachAsync(async (doc) => {

    res.push(quoteMapper(doc)); // mapped to a specific schema

    if (i === 50) {
      await sendQuotesTest(res); 
      i = 0;
      res = [];
    }
    i += 1;
  });
}
```

The version of Mongoose: 
The version of MongoDB:

Comment: "mongoose": "^5.0.8",
MongoDB : 3.6.12

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to get the number of pending documents from the cursor. The nature of the stream concept contradicts this approach somehow.

When working with node streams I always use the [highland.js](https://highlandjs.org/) lib. highland.js is for streams what [lodash](https://lodash.com) is for Arrays. It makes stream handling really simple and intuitive.

I wrote a little demo app to show how highland can be used to solve your problem:

```js
const h = require("highland")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const moment = require("moment")
const faker = require("faker")
const Promise = require("bluebird")

/////// Model ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const Quote = mongoose.model("Quote", {
   lastPriceRequest: Number,
   updatedAt: Date,
})

/////// START ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const from = moment().subtract(20, "days")
const to = moment()
console.log(`query from='${from.format("L")}' to='${to.format("L")}'`)

connect()
   // .then(() => addRandomQuotes(100))
   .then(() => getQuotesStream(from.toDate(), to.toDate()))
   .then(handleQuotesStream)
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.error)

/////// FNs ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

async function connect () {
   await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/highland-test-db', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
   })
}

async function addRandomQuotes (count) {
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      let quote = {
         lastPriceRequest: faker.commerce.price(),
         updatedAt: faker.date.recent(60),
      }
      const Q = new Quote(quote)
      await Q.save()
   }
   console.log(`created ${count} random quotes`)
}

function getQuotesStream (from, to) {
   return Quote
      .find()
      .where("updatedAt").gte(from)
      .where("updatedAt").lt(to)
      .where("lastPriceRequest").ne(null)
      .sort("updatedAt")
      .lean()
      .cursor()
}

function handleQuotesStream (stream) {
   let count = 0
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      h(stream)
         .tap(() => count++)
         .batch(50)
         .map(sendBatchToApiEndpoint)
         .series()
         .done(() => resolve({count}))
   })
}

function sendBatchToApiEndpoint (items) {
   console.log(`sending batch of ${items.length} items`)
   // send the data here / wrap the promise into highland (like return h(promise))
   return h(Promise.resolve(items))
}
```

It allows you to send all queried documents in batches. All batches will have size 50. The last batch size will be arbitrary (<= 50). But you don't have to care about the batch sizes yourself. This will be managed by highland.

Demo output:

```
>node highland-test.js
query from='02/08/2020' to='02/28/2020'
sending batch of 50 items
sending batch of 50 items
sending batch of 50 items
sending batch of 50 items
sending batch of 50 items
sending batch of 47 items
{ count: 297 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer was very helpful!